# How to make a vector of two numbers into inclusive sequence in R?

Tags: r, performance, sequence

I have a vector (or matrix, etc.) with two numbers.

Is there a function or other short "one-line" trick to making these numbers an inclusive sequence?

For example:

If I have a vector containing the numbers 1 and 15.
I want to quickly apply a function (or trick) to generate a new vector containing 1:15 (1,2,3,4,5,6...15)

I understand I can use the `seq` function to create sequences, but this would require me to write out both digits from my vector (or matrix, etc.) as "from" and "to".

- In an example where indexing of data.frames, lists or matrices creates long lines of text, it would be nice not to have to repeat those strings of text for both from/to arguments.

Example:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5, c = 1:5, d = 1:5, e = 1:5, f = 1:5)

#Too messy/long/time-consuming if my column names are longer/more complex:   
  names(dat)[names(dat) %in% c('a','b','c','d','e')]

#Too much coding text (I'm assuming it can be done simpler):
  names(dat)[seq(from = which(names(dat) == 'a'), to = which(names(dat) == 'e'))]

#So how could I do something like the sequence example, but with less text?
  #perhaps using: which(names(dat) %in% c('a','e'))  in some way...?
```

Comment: `do.call(seq, as.list(match(c("a", "e"), names(dat))))` maybe

Comment: For your example, `names(subset(dat,,a:e))`

Comment: @A.Webb: that's fantastic! But I wonder why you say "for your example." Is this simply b/c you use my example to inform an example of your method's usage, or because you think that perhaps this isn't always an applicable approach?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I've timed 100,000 iterations each of the 4 methods described thus far (my 2 from the question, Rich's and A. Webb's). Interestingly, the subset method is the slowest (mean 2.26e-4 sec), followed by the do.call method (0.54e-4 sec), then the seq method (0.47e-4 sec) and finally the simple listing method was the fastest (0.30e-4 sec). So speed is inversely correlated with code complexity -- more accurately, code length -- for this example...

Comment: @theforestecologist I meant for `data.frames`. This wouldn't work as given for vectors. And yes, you generally pay for abstraction in R, unfortunately.